# ruby regex replace the corresponding string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

```
str = "1627207:132069:color:green;20518:28421:size:62cm"

aliastr = "20518:28421:S;20518:28358:L;20518:28357:M;1627207:132069:red"
```

How to dynamic replace str to "1627207:132069:color:red;20518:28421:size:S".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a pretty unclear question, but I think I got it now. Your `aliastr` contains mappings which control the replacements, i.e., the key '20518:28421:' should map to value 'S' and the key '1627207:132069:' should map to 'red'. Then you want to search for those keys in `str` and replace their current value with that new value. This does that:

```
str = "1627207:132069:color:green;20518:28421:size:62cm"
aliastr = "20518:28421:S;20518:28358:L;20518:28357:M;1627207:132069:red"

mapping = Hash[aliastr.scan(/(\d+:\d+:)(.*?)(?:;|$)/)]
# mapping = {"20518:28421:"=>"S", "20518:28358:"=>"L", "20518:28357:"=>"M", "1627207:132069:"=>"red"}

replaced = str.gsub(/(\d+:\d+:)(\w+:).*?(;|$)/) do |match|
  key = $1
  value = mapping[$1]
  key + $2 + value + $3
end

p replaced
# => "1627207:132069:color:red;20518:28421:size:S"
```

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how to describe.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, and probably contains an error ("color:red" in your wanted result vs. "red" in aliastr).

You may try something like this:

```
str = "1627207:132069:color:green;20518:28421:size:62cm"
aliastr = "20518:28421:S;20518:28358:L;20518:28357:M;1627207:132069:red"
replacements = aliastr.split(";").map{|s| parts=s.split(":"); [/#{parts[0]}:#{parts[1]}:.*/,s]}
src = str.split(";")
src.map{|s| replacements.each{|r| s.sub!(r[0],r[1])}; s }.join(";")
```

Comment: No, I think he wanted to keep both 'color' and 'size' in the resulting string. So 'color:red' and 'size:S' instead of just 'red' and 'S'.

Comment: @Trygve Flathen  Nice.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers You're right, the question is now edited. That makes my general method here less suited for the task.